# Invariant Lagrangians of a connection and its derivatives: how do they look like?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, connections, general-relativity

Let
$$
L=L(\Gamma,\partial\Gamma,\ldots,\partial^n\Gamma)
$$
be a Lagrangian depending on a **linear symmetric connection** $\Gamma$ on the tangent space of a manifold $M$ together with its derivatives up to order $n$ (i.e., $L$ is a smooth function on the $n^\textrm{th}$ jet prolongation $J^n(C(M))$ of the affine bundle $C(M)\to M$ of such connections).

> QUESTION. Is it true that $L$ is invariant w.r.t. the group of diffeomorphisms on $M$, if and only if $L$ can be expressed as a function of $\Gamma,K,\nabla K\,\ldots,\nabla^{n-1} K$?

By the symbol $K$ I mean the **curvature** of $\Gamma$, whereas I denoted by $\nabla$ the **covariant derivative** w.r.t. $\Gamma$.

The implication, in one direction, is obvious, and mathematical folklore has it that the other implication is valid as well - but I need a reference! I'm aware that the question - in a slightly different formulation - [has been answered by Weyl](https://mathoverflow.net/q/109669/22606), but he was dealing with a metric, which, a priori, is absent here.

Comment: If you want $L$ to be a *Lagrangian*, you don't want it to be a *function* on $J^n(C(M))$.  Instead,  $L(\Gamma,\ldots,\partial^n\Gamma)$ should be an $m$-form on $M$ (where $m$ is the dimension of $M$).  Otherwise, you can't integrate $L$ over $M$ to obtain a functional on torsion-free connections.  In other words, $L$ should be a bundle mapping $L:J^n(C(M))\to \Lambda^m(T^*M)$ that is Diff$(M)$-equivariant.  (Of course, for the ultra-careful, even this isn't right because $M$ is not assumed to be oriented, so $L$ should actually assign an *$m$-density* to each torsion-free connection.)

Comment: @RobertBryant sure, I've been sloppy. I used the name "Lagrangian", instead of "function", just because the question arose in the Lagrangian formulation of certain extended theories of gravity. Of course, my question is about the coefficient of $d^m\boldsymbol{x}$ in the correct expression $L d^m\boldsymbol{x}$ I should have used above. This is the typical "folkloristic question" appeared in mathematical physics: everyone claims it is true, but so far nobody was able to give me the slightest evidence of its validity. I'm sure an expert of differential invariants should know how to work it out.

Comment: "Coefficient of $d^mx$": in the metric case you have a natural volume form (as a natural function of the metric). What are you using as $d^m x$? // In some sense the natural invariants for your linear connection are the Pontrjagin forms, which by Chern-Weil are polynomial in the curvature. But this is most likely not what you are asking about.

Comment: @WillieWong as $d^m\boldsymbol{x}$ I'm using an arbitrary volume form, just to identify horizontal $m$-forms on $J^n(C(M))$ with smooth functions. So: yes, my question is about natural invariants (if by "natural" one means  $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$-invariant) of order $\leq n$ of torsion-free linear connections on $T M$. Now: what did you mean by "In some sense"? And why polynomials in the curvature should be enough? This way - I guess - you get only first-order invariants. What about the higher-order ones? Are they polynomial in the covariant derivatives of the curvature?

Comment: 1. Your "arbitrary" volume form contributes arbitrarily to the change of your Lagrangian density under diffeomorphism. You can't hope to have the $L d^m x$ be invariant under all diffeomorphisms and $L$ be invariant under all diffeomorphisms while keeping an arbitrary $d^mx$. This is the essence of Robert Bryant's first comment. Two possible choices are to let the volume form depend on the connection (as in the case of Weyl's theorem, where it depends on the metric) or to fix a volume form and consider only Diffs that preserve the volume form. Or there are other cases, but you have to specify.

Comment: 2. The sense of naturality I refer to is, for example, that used in Kolar-Michor-Slovak's "Natural Operations in Differential Geometry". In section 33.4 they give the proof that the only natural tensors that can be constructed from linear symmetric connections are those corresponding to covariant derivatives of the curvature and their tensor products and natural contractions. In section 33.5 they show that adding in symmetry considerations, the natural differential forms are those corresponding to chern/pontrjagin classes.

Comment: ... In section 33.7 they show that when a metric is in play, your allowable natural operations are enlarged (by the $\sharp$ and $\flat$ operators and metric contractions, as well as tensor products with the metric volume form). This together with the result of section 33.4 give essentially the proof of Weyl's theorem. But without these additional operations the set of natural objects is somewhat smaller.

Comment: @WillieWong: ok, you answered my question! Believe it or not, I've asked this to several physicists - some of them with a long publication record in GR - and the answer was always the same "I'm almost certain it is true, but I cannot prove it, and I wouldn't know where to look"!